# Omnifaces 1.8.1 WebXML parse exception

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException:` while trying to invoke the method `java.lang.String.trim()` of an object returned from `org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent()`.

When I use

```
List<String> welcomeFiles = WebXml.INSTANCE.getWelcomeFiles();
```

from a ManagedBean as below:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LogoffControl implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * log4j logger
     */
    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LogFactory
            .getLogger(LogoffControl.class);

    public String logoff() {
        List<String> welcomeFiles = WebXml.INSTANCE.getWelcomeFiles();
        try {
            Faces.redirect(welcomeFiles.get(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Redirect Failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Faces.invalidateSession();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException`, saying that I may have a typo in my web.xml.  I've debugged it, and I see that the result of the xpath execution in WebXML.java line 414 succeeds, and I make it into the loop on line 418

```
welcomeFiles.add(welcomeFileList.item(i).getTextContent().trim());
```

In the debugger `welcomeFileList.item(i)` evaluates to `<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>`, however calling `welcomeFileList.item(i).getTextContent()` results in null.  I can't figure it out... What am I missing?

In the log:

```
Jan 11, 2015 1:36:37 PM org.omnifaces.config.WebXml init
SEVERE: WebXml failed to initialize. Perhaps your web.xml contains a typo?
java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method java.lang.String.trim() of an object returned from org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent()
at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.parseWelcomeFiles(WebXml.java:418
```

Oracle JSF 2.1.26, Omnifaces 1.8.1, servlet 2.5, sapjvm6.1 (Java6), on SAPNetweaver 7.4 server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>tablemaint-web</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    ....
</webapp>
```

Comment: Awkward. I supect a bug in JAXP parser being used. Which JAXP parser is being used in the environment? Can you try it locally with `getFirstChild().getNodeValue()` instead of `getTextContent()`?

Comment: I can confirm that getFirstChild().getNodeValue() does in fact work.  The JAXP provider is from SAP com.sap.engine.lib.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl

Comment: I'm now noticing that the WebXML class is initialized automatically by omnifaces faces-config.xml (I think through OmniPartialViewContext config), so I get this NullPointerException even without my specific code above.  As you would expect, on this platform the other getTextContent() methods throw the same error.  I have little hope SAP would fix this bug, is there any chance of an omnifaces workaround?

Comment: I can replace `getTextContent()` by `getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`. It's after all only a shorthand for getting the node value of text nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the JAXP parser used. This is supposed to work normally. The SAP JAXP parser is apparently somehow not recognizing a text node as a text node. The [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) will namely return `null` on e.g. a document node and document type node.

The work around of using `getFirstChild().getNodeValue()` instead of `getTextContent()` appears to work fine (and should continue to work normally on decent JAXP parsers), so this has been [implemented](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/bf31d4dab718069573a23dc383ed5350ceb57fe3) and the fix is available in today's [1.11 snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.11-SNAPSHOT/) (and [2.1 snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.1-SNAPSHOT/) for 2.x users).